Smartleads to Vendasta using Zapier
Anyone here that uses Vendasta and Smartlead?
We’d like to use Zapier to connect Smartlead to Vendasta wherein the process we want to create in Zapier is we want Smartleads leads when they finish certain sequences gets added in Vendasta campaigns by using Zapier
Is that possible?
I tried integrating vendasta and use webhooks for smartlead but got confused on what to do
